# Latex can't run because it finds a bracket too many?

Tags: brackets

When I run Texworks, I get the issue saying that there should be a bracket too many in the paragraph that is marked with yellow. If I run it in overleaf, I get the same error, yet Overleaf is still capable to run it. I also looked at paragraphs around this paragraph (not in the MWE), but cant find anything. Can somebody help me with this issue?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{setspace}
% margin settings for interview pages
\usepackage[left=1in,right=2.5in,marginparwidth=1.5in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\codedtext}[3]{%
\sethlcolor{#1}%
\marginnote{\setstretch{1}\hl{#3}}\hl{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
% margin settings for regular pages
\newgeometry{left=1in,right=1in,marginparwidth=1in}
This is a normal page with margins set by the \texttt{\textbackslash newgeometry} command.
This settings will be in effect until \texttt{\textbackslash restoregeometry} is
used. The following page shows a coded interview with adjusted margins.
\newpage
% restore to margin settings defined in preamble
\restoregeometry
\onehalfspacing
\noindent \textbf{Speaker:  }
 \codedtext{yellow}{They are now working on an overflow terminal, which specialists then say: 'Then it's in the wrong place and then? Then we shift the problem to the other side, it doesn't get cheaper on that,’ and then someone says to construct more cranes, but then someone responds 'that's really nice such a terminal, I have 15 cranes and the demand varies from 2 and 30 cranes. Do you know how much crane and quay costs? I'm not going to put down 30 cranes for the occasional peak, because an inland skipper has to wait. I'm not going to get paid for that.' So everyone's looking at each other a little bit, so that's also the question of looking at the system. Everyone's holding each other in a system that doesn't work well.}{\tiny Capacity issues \\ Obstacles to innovation: Money}\\


\newpage
\newgeometry{left=1in,right=1in,marginparwidth=1in}
This page has the same margins as the first page.



\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a fix typo `’` that you should delete.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! It was indeed the typo that Sebastiano was mentioning. Was stuck with this for over an hour, but finally fixed it thanks to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Sebastiano, there is a `’` in the coded text argument: `get cheaper on that,’ and then`.  This throws everything off.

Generally speaking, TeX uses the backtick ` (up near `esc`) to open quotes, and the apostrophe `'` to close quotes (and as an apostrophe).